# How to assert return type of React.Component instance?

Tags: typescript, reactjs, jsx

In typescript, I have a React Component, *Cell*,

```
class Cell extends Component<void, void> {
...
}
```

and when I use it, i.e.

```
<Cell />
```

The return type I'm getting is `JSX.Element`.

Instead, I am trying to assert that the return value is an instance of `Cell`, not `JSX.Element`, how can I go about doing this?

It fails as it says

```
Type `Element` is not assignable to type `Cell`
```

Comment: Please show your assertion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am trying to assert that the return value is an instance of Cell, not JSX.Element

Use `React.ReactElement<Cell>`. e.g.

```
const foo: React.ReactElement<Cell> = <Cell/>; // Okay
const bar: React.ReactElement<Cell> = <NotCell/>; // Error!
```

Comment: Is there any way to enforce the same constraint if `Cell` is a React functional component?